# vb msgbox after completion of a process

Tags: vb.net-2010, msgbox

I am running a batch file with shell function in VB2010 with the following command

```
Shell("C:\test.bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

This process takes a lot of time to complete, might even take a day to complete depending on the input file.

I want a MsgBox to display a "Job Finished" msg when the process is finished.
something like

```
MsgBox("Job Finished")
```

How do I do that. I am very new to VB, so please help me with full code.
Thank you

Comment: Open the batch project and at the end of the method, just paste your code  `MsgBox("Job Finished")`

Comment: @Nadeem_MK sorry, this didn't work

Comment: Why don't just run it as a process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will basically wait till the process finishes (*It finishes by exiting. as most batch files do*. I'm only making an assumption though).

```
 Sub Main()
            Dim P As New Process
            P.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\test.bat"
            Try
                P.Start()
                P.WaitForExit()
                MsgBox("Process completed successfully")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error:" & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: I have already done this and this is working just as desired, but thank you anyway for your suggestion.